# Why is no data received on my read of a TcpListener configured socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener

I am able to make a connection on a socket using TcpListener, but I cannot read any data.  I never get past the DataAvailable check in the following C# code (note, this is a summary):

```
// Listen for a connection
m_host = “127.0.0.1”;
int ListenerPort = 7777;
IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse(m_host);
TcpListener m_listener = new TcpListener(localAddr, ListenerPort);
m_listener.Start();
TcpClient m_client = m_listener.AcceptTcpClient();
if (m_client.Connected)
{      // We are connected.  Create a stream for handling the RX/TX messaging on the socket.
   NetworkStream clientStream = m_client.GetStream();
   if (clientStream.DataAvailable)
   {      // Read something
      byte[] message = new byte[14];
      int bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 14);
   }
}
```

Does something need to be sent back on the socket before the client knows it can send data?

Comment: Your host is the loopback port. Are you trying to connect to yourself?

Comment: If you send nothing to the socket, nothing will be received.

Comment: You're checking whether there's any data available *immediately* after the socket has been connected. There may well not be any data available *yet*, but only due to timing. Normally you'd either use asynchronous IO, or use a separate thread for each connection, with a blocking read. Don't assume the whole message can be read in one go, either.

Comment: @JonSkeet That probably is the answer, with a bonus.

Comment: The client program I am testing with is running on the same host as my server code.  The client program is sending data as soon as the connection is established, but I am not receiving the data.

Comment: In my actual code which uses threads, there is a sleep being executed when the DataAvailable returns false. Right now, I am just trying to read some portion of the data being transmitted.

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is that you are creating a TcpListener (i.e. an underlying socket), accept a connection and immediately check for data. It is likely that the client did not send anything yet and you leave the outer if-clause without reading anything. Depending on what you are trying to to, you might try something like

```
if(m_client.Connected) 
{
    NetworkStream clientStream = m_client.GetStream();
    while(!m_client.DataAvailable) //be careful here - maybe introduce a timeout
    {}
    byte[] message = new byte[14];
    int bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 14);
}
```

Anyway, without knowing what exactly you are trying to do, I can't help you any further. The code *might* work, but I'd suggest a redesign, for from what I can tell by your snippet, your code suffers bad design choices (although this can arise from your summarization).

Comment: Yes, the summary code I showed was just a summary.  The code is designed within a better construct of threads.  I have tried sleeping to wait for data.

Comment: Also, the client code is actually a VB6 application, but that should not matter as long as the socket is handled as a TCP Socket.  I believe the client connects to an AF_INET socket.  The socket on the C# sharp side uses an addressFamily of InterNetwork.  I don't know if that would be a conflict.

Comment: I think I found my problem.  I learned that the client program I am trying to receive data from requires a ping type message to be sent to it first - just the protocol that is being used for this project.